# error instantiating servlet class when trying to access a database

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, ojdbc

I've just gotten into servlets and I cannot display the information on tomcat.
This is my class with the doGet method

```
public class WhoisOlder extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public WhoisOlder() {
    super();
}
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String OJDBC_Driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    final String DB_URL = "";
    final String USER = "";
    final String PASS = "";

    try {
        Class.forName(OJDBC_Driver);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT GEBDAT FROM KLASSE");

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("GEBDAT"));
        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException se) {

        System.out.println("SQL Exception: " + se.getMessage());
        se.printStackTrace(System.out);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I get the "Error instantiating servlet class" error, when I run the code on my browser. I have checked if the servlet name, servlet URL is correct, which it is. Is the code false in my class, which preventing to instantiate the class?

EDIT: Below is the exception and the root log.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WhoisOlder
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2466)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2455)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

EDIT 2: My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">
<description>OJDBCAnbindung</description>
<display-name>OJDBCAnbindung</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>WhoisOlder</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>WhoisOlder</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>WhoisOlder</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/WhoisOlder</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: It says `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WhoisOlder`. What does your web.xml look like?

Comment: Is your filename the same as your class name i.e. `WhoisOlder.java`? Is it on your CLASSPATH?And since you didn't specify a package name, is your `WhoisOlder.java` file directly underneath your `src` folder?

Comment: Do you mean the project name by filename? My project name is OJDBCAnbindung. It is on my classpath and i have default package which is under src.

Comment: I assume you have a `.war` file that you deploy to tomcat, right? Try run `jar tf <your-war>.war` from your command line, and see if the `.class` file containing your servlet is there. Presumably, that file will be named `WhoIsOlder.class`.

Comment: Also, I should mention that I assume your servlet codes compile? I don't see any `import` statements such as `import javax.servlet.*;`, `import javax.servlet.http.*;` near the top of your codes...

Comment: What is the package that your servlet is in?
What IDE do you use?
Do you use the application by placing .war file manually to server?

Answer (score 0):

Put your servlet in a package, compile the .class file to the WEB-INF/classes folder. Change your web.xml to add the package name to your servlet's class file.